# Best way to architect a TCP/IP server for client-server communications?

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets, tcp

I'm going to be writing a native C++ Windows service that needs to gather and store data from client desktop computers, potentially thousands of them. The data is simple such as CPU%, Memory, and some other data from client software running on the desktops.

What's the best way to architect this client-server communication?
Named Pipes? TCP server/client? Windows sockets? WCF? Something else?
Or would it be best to run a SQL Server on the server and have the clients establish a connection with the database and send the information that way?

I could run a multi-threaded Named Pipe server within the service on the server, but I don't want to generate a thread per connection within the service with thousands of clients b/c that would consume too many server subsystem resources. Clients will be on the local network and over WANs.

Any guidance is appreciated!

Comment: Standard solution is to use WMI.  No need to install any software on the client machine, it can be done remotely.

Comment: Do you need to send data from the client asynchronously?

Comment: I'm getting standard data plus other non-OS data, and I have a client running on the desktops. My experience with WMI is it takes up a lot of resources just querying a dozen or so computers. Or is WCF better perhaps?

Comment: Sure, data can be sent asynchronously.

Comment: "thousands of them" is ambiguous. How many event/data per second? How do you make use of the collected data? How much development effect you willing to spend? It can go from simple web+db to a tailer-made tcp server.

Comment: How often is the client sending data to the server? Do you really need sockets or you could use standard HTTP connections?

Comment: Not sure how often yet. If I polled all clients from the server it'd be at once, but a "pulse" maybe every 10 seconds.

Comment: I would rather push the data from the client every x seconds, making an HTTP post to the server (instead or re-inventing another protocol).

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to write a server from scratch; you can already access the Windows Performance Counters using the Performance Data Helper functions documented here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373214(v=vs.85).aspx

In particular, [PdhAddCounter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372204(v=vs.85).aspx) lets you specify a query path which can be on a remote machine, as specified here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373193(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Right, PDH works just fine, but I didn't mention that I'm getting non-OS data from a client program running on the desktops. I'll edit the description.

Comment: Great, then you can use the Windows API for providing counters to get your data into the system, and use PDH to get it out on the server.  Docs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373165(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Seems pretty large and inefficient to have thousands of threads in a process to poll the thousands of clients.